# Restart failed processes on available machine

Tags: failover

I'm working on a system that has about 50 processes distributed across about 4 different machines. The architecture allows for any process to run on any machine, but only allows each process to run on one machine. Having the same process running twice on the same machine or twice on different machines causes big problems.

Is there any off the shelf software that would monitor the processes on the machines and restart them if they die? And if a machine dies, then restart the processes on one of the available machines? And ensure that we never have the same process running more than once across the whole system?

Answer (score 1):

Product recommendations are off-topic, but the term your looking for is a **[cluster manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_manager)** and **[high availability clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster)**.